# How I can get search form value in Drupal 7

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-7, search-form

I've tried to implement a new module that catches the keys written in the default search form and displays other results than the default search result page. With these other results I will make an external query, which is put in a special block.

Any idea on how to do this?

I've tried to use a custom module making a "hook_alter_form " with no success.

In other words :

I have a function like this:

```
 function my_function_name_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){ 
     switch($form_id){ 
      case 'search-block-form':
     //Here i want to catch the text that i wrote in the search box 
     break; 
    } 
  }
```

Thank u!

Comment: You should show us what you've tried and what about it failed. As it is, this question is very broad and hard to answer.

Comment: **Ok, in de module that i've created i have a function like this:**

`function my_function_name_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){
        switch($form_id){
        case 'search-block-form':
        //Here i want to catch the text that i wrote in the search box
        break;
       } 
        
}`

Thank u!

Comment: You should probably put this into the original question for readability and anyone who comes after. Use the 'edit' link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Ok sorry, i'm newbie in this forum, there u go!

Comment: You need to use search_block_form not search-block-form

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the search query in order to show other results:

```
function mymodule_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query){
  $is_search = FALSE;
  foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
    if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
      $is_search = TRUE;
    }
  }

 if ($is_search) {
    global $language; 

    $db_or = db_or();
    $db_or->condition('n.type', 'event', '=');
    $db_or->condition('n.type', 'real_sitio', '=');
    $query->condition($db_or);

    $query->condition('n.language' , $language->language, '=');
 } 
}
```

This is a bit performance killer so there's a patch for drupal at http://drupal.org/node/1435834 that adds a hook for making the alter directly in the search query:

So finally it would look like:

```
function mymodule_search_query_search_node_alter(&$query) {
  $query->condition('n.type', 'article', '=');
}
```